# Installed Windows 7 boot to VHD, now need to install (dual boot) Fedora

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, vhd

I'm usually on StackOverflow, but had a question about dual booting.  I have been happily using Windows 7 booting to VHD ever since the RC.  Now I am taking a class where the instructor wants us to install Fedora 12 KDE and, obviously, I want to keep Windows 7 and dual boot to this system.  I'd rather not use a virtual machine like VirtualBox, since we need to do some things in regards to writing software drivers and the fact that it is going to be slower than booting to a physical machine (that said, there's nothing like boot to VHD for Linux/GRUB, is there?).

My dilemma is that once I install it I am afraid I will screw up the Windows 7 boot-loader and be unable to boot to Windows 7 because it is a VHD file.

Any thoughts on if this is true and how I can accomplish this safely?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Grub](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) boot manager is quite **safe** to use.

Setting up the boot to VHD in Windows 7 is very easy, so even if it did "screw up" it won't be hard to set up again. Following the steps on [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx) and you're set.

My current configuration is, Windows 7 RTM, with an additional Win 7 VHD, on top of that is an Ubuntu installation, it's boot manager doesn't have any impact on the Windows boot list.

Once I select "Windows 7" under "Other Operating Systems:" in the grub boot manager, I'm presented with my two Windows 7 boot options.

Comment: Did you install Windows 7 before or after your Ubuntu install?

Comment: Windows was installed first.